# How does Ruby Mocha stub a nested hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, hash, ruby-mocha

I have a method here that needs to be mocked using Mocha, but currently i have no clue how to mock the nested hash here.

`Products.new(:A => "aa", :B => "bb").containers['container_A'].elements['element_b']`

So far, i know how to stub `Products.new(:A => "aa", :B => "bb")`, but have no idea with the hash part after it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a `hash`/`OpenStruct`?

```
require 'ostruct'

product.expects(:containers).
        returns('container_A' => OpenStruct.new(:elements => {'element_b' => 'expected_value'}))

puts product.containers['container_A'].elements['element_b']
# => expected_value
```